# How can I combine two arrays to create a key value pair with Jolt?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I've already created a spec to convert my JSON input

```json
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "row": [
        "row1",
        "row2",
        "row3"
      ],
      "header": [
        "header1",
        "header2",
        "header3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "row": [
        "row4",
        "row5",
        "row6"
      ],
      "header": [
        "header4",
        "header5",
        "header6"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

to convert to key-value pairs as following object result :

```json
{
  "header1" : "row1",
  "header2" : "row2",
  "header3" : "row3",
  "header4" : "row4",
  "header5" : "row5",
  "header6" : "row6"
}
```

Is this possible to do using Jolt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the following **shift** transformation spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*s": { // rows array
        "*": {
          "&(1,1)": { // row array
            "*": {
              "@": "@(3,header[&1])"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

- **`"*s": {`**  stands for row**s**
- **`"&(1,1)": {`** ->  not immediate(*zero*th) level but one more level up by using **`&(1,`** and grab the value there the first asterisk exists by **`&(..,1)`**
- **`"@": "@(3,header[&1])"`** -> **`3`** levels needed as stated at the right hand side traverse the colon
  as well in order to reach the level of **`&(1,1)`** which is used to
  represent the **`"row"`** array along with **`&1`** representation to go one level up the tree to reach the indexes of the array **`"row"`** while matching with the values of **`"row"`** through use of **`@`** on the left hand side

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is there a copy/paste error in your input? Judging by your desired output, the second object's `header` array should be `["header4", "header5", "header6"]`. If that's the case, this spec should work:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "rows": {
        "*": {
          "header": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "@(3,row[#2])": "&"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```